# How to change Thunderbird icon theme?

Tags: thunderbird

I got Thunderbird 24.1.0 from Portableapps.com. Same folder unpacked into Win7 and XP.

- When run on WIn7 I see all icons (get mail, write, chat...) are gray themed.
- When run under WinXP all icons are another, they are colored and of other style.

How to change icons theme? Can't find an option.

Answer (score 0):

Found that Thunderbd has Firefox-like extensions dialog.
Need to go into upper Thunderbd menu, and call command "Manage add-ons". Then need to call tab which contains appearance add-ons. Then need to install there any icons add-on. E.g. "Standard icons".

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to replace the [ICNS file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format) inside the application. To access the contents of the application, you right-click on the app, then select *Show Package Contents*. The location of the ICNS file should be `Thunderbird.app/Contents/Resources/Thunderbird.icns`